# one to zero or one relationship in entity framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have 2 standard entities :

Group :

```
[Table("CONTROL_GROUP", Schema = "CONTROL")]
public partial class Group
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    [Column("ID")]
    public decimal Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("NAME")]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual GroupMetier GroupMetier { get; set; }
}
```

GroupMetier:

```
[Table("CONTROL_GROUP_METIER", Schema = "CONTROL")]
public partial class GroupMetier
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column("GROUP_ID")]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("NAME")]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

In my model builder, I defined the relashionship as follow :

```
// GroupMetier 0..1 <-> 1 Group
modelBuilder.Entity<GroupMetier>()
    .HasRequired<Group>(gm => gm.Group)
    .WithOptional(g => g.GroupMetier)
```

However, on execution, when I try to retrive the groups with this linq :

```
_context.Groups.Where(item => item.GroupMetier != null)
```

The generated sql failed to execute :

```
SELECT 
    "Extent3"."GROUP_ID" AS "GROUP_ID", 
    "Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", 
    "Extent1"."NAME" AS "NAME", 
    "Extent2"."GROUP_ID" AS "GROUP_ID1"
FROM   "CONTROL"."CONTROL_GROUP" "Extent1"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "CONTROL"."CONTROL_GROUP_METIER" "Extent2" ON "Extent1"."ID" = "Extent2"."GroupId"
    INNER JOIN "CONTROL"."CONTROL_GROUP_METIER" "Extent3" ON "Extent1"."ID" = "Extent3"."GroupId"
WHERE (1 = 1)
```

The problem come obviously from entity trying to join on an non existing `"Extent2"."GroupId"` column  instead of the right  `"Extent2"."GROUP_ID"`

Have I failed to declare something somewhere for this relashionship to work ?

Edit : As requested, the CONTROL.CONTROL_GROUP_METIER table :

```
CREATE TABLE CONTROL.CONTROL_GROUP_METIER
(
  GROUP_ID  INTEGER                             NOT NULL,
  NAME      VARCHAR2(200 CHAR)                  NOT NULL
)
TABLESPACE CONTROL_DATA
RESULT_CACHE (MODE DEFAULT)
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONTROL.CONTROL_GROUP_METIER_PK ON CONTROL.CONTROL_GROUP_METIER
(GROUP_ID)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE CONTROL_DATA
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
NOPARALLEL;


ALTER TABLE CONTROL.CONTROL_GROUP_METIER ADD (
  CONSTRAINT CONTROL_GROUP_METIER_PK
  PRIMARY KEY
  (GROUP_ID)
  USING INDEX CONTROL.CONTROL_GROUP_METIER_PK
  ENABLE VALIDATE);

ALTER TABLE CONTROL.CONTROL_GROUP_METIER ADD (
  CONSTRAINT CONTROL_GROUP_METIER_R01 
  FOREIGN KEY (GROUP_ID) 
  REFERENCES CONTROL.CONTROL_GROUP (ID)
  ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are using fluent API along with data annotation ? you can use one of them also if this is a web application it is better to not use virtual keyword

Comment: I'm using the fluent api to define the relationships and data annotation for everything else. As I have ~ 130 entities in my model, I can't define everything by fluent as it would be a pain to maintain and for an unknow reason the `ForeignKey` data annotation don't seem to work at all in my model. I also have to use virtual to have lazy loading as doing a full load of any of my entities would be way too long, loading thoussands of object when i only need to check the properties on one.

Comment: Can you show the `CONTROL_GROUP_METIER` table?

Comment: The main question is if you have a separate FK column in `CONTROL_GROUP_METIER` table or the PK is also used as FK (which seem impossible because the `GROUP_ID` column type is `int` while `CONTROL_GROUP.ID` is `decimal`).

Comment: So you really are trying to use PK as FK. But EF does not allow setting up FK relationship between columns with different types. Why `ID` is `decimal`?

Comment: **Thanks Ivan, that was it !** It was a copy-past remanenet of an old entity from which i had created this one, it seem that the different type confuse EF and has triggered this unexpected response. If you would like to formulate that as a response, I will gladly check it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have I failed to declare something somewhere for this relashionship to work ?

Your configuration is just fine for so called [Shared Primary Key Association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations) and normally would produce a migration like this (just to test the mapping):

```
CreateTable(
    "CONTROL.CONTROL_GROUP_METIER",
    c => new
        {
            GROUP_ID = c.Int(nullable: false),
            NAME = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 200),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.GROUP_ID)
    .ForeignKey("CONTROL.CONTROL_GROUP", t => t.GROUP_ID)
    .Index(t => t.GROUP_ID);
```

However, it actually produces this:

```
CreateTable(
    "CONTROL.CONTROL_GROUP_METIER",
    c => new
        {
            GROUP_ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            NAME = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 200),
            Group_Id = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.GROUP_ID)
    .ForeignKey("CONTROL.CONTROL_GROUP", t => t.Group_Id)
    .Index(t => t.Group_Id);
```

which as you can see is not what you want.

Why is that? To better understand, let apply the explicit `ForeignKey` attribute to the `Group` property:

```
[ForeignKey("GroupId")]
public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
```

Now the migration fails with the following error:

> GroupMetier_Group_Target_GroupMetier_Group_Source: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'GroupId' on entity 'GroupMetier' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity 'Group' in the referential constraint 'GroupMetier_Group'.

So the problem is that the `Group.Id` property type is `decimal` and `GroupMetier.GroupId` property type is `int`, in which case EF fails to recognize the relationship and tries to use [One-to-One Foreign Key Association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations) which of course doesn't match your database model.

How to fix it? It's hard to tell, but you somehow should make both properties `int` or `decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the ForeignKey annotation?

```
[ForeignKey("GROUP_ID")]
public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
```

Comment: @remy-grandin Also afterwards inspect if the associations have been created as expected in the database.

Comment: I'm in a code first with existing database model, so my tables and relations are already created by our dba. Also, for an unknown reason, the `ForeignKey` data annotation don't seem to work in my model

Answer (score 0):

in fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GroupMetier>()
.HasRequired<Group>(gm => gm.Group)
.WithOptional(g => g.GroupMetier)
.Map(g => g.MapKey("GROUP_ID"));
```

Comment: It gives me a model validation exception : `GROUP_ID: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'GROUP_ID' is already defined.`.

Comment: did you try this 
       `modelBuilder.Entity<GroupMetier>()
      .HasRequired<Group>(gm => gm.Group)
      .WithOptional(g => g.GroupMetier)
       .Map(g => g.MapKey("GROUP_ID"))
       .HasForeignKey(g => g.GroupId)`